# For iid $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, get sufficient statistic $T = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2$, how to find unbiased estimator of $\sigma^a$

Tags: normal-distribution, unbiased-estimator, sufficient-statistics

For $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, we define a sufficient statistic $T = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2$. There is a positive number $a$. My question is how to find unbiased estimator of $\sigma^a$ using the sufficient statistics $T$.

I know the unbiased estimate of $\sigma^2$ but I don't think we can simply add power to the estimate of $\sigma^2$ to get the unbiased estimate of $\sigma^a$.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your sufficient statistic doesn't make any sense - what are you actually summing?

Comment: @jcken, I am summing up the $X_i^2$. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

By writing the $X_i$'s as $X_i=\sigma \epsilon_i$, where the $\epsilon_i\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ are standard Gaussians, $$T=\sigma^2 \sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon_i^2$$ writes as $\sigma^2$ times a fixed rv, distributed as a $\chi^2_n$. Therefore, $T^{a/2}$ writes as $\sigma^a$ times a fixed rv, distributed as a $\chi^a_n$ variate. The resolution of the question thus reduces to finding the [expectation of a $\chi^a_n$ variate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution#Noncentral_moments).